# IFS and moving through single positions in directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ifs

I have two questions .

1. I have found following code line in script : `IFS=${IFS#??}`
   I would like to understand what it is exactly doing ?
2. When I am trying to perform something in every place from directory like eg.:

   ```
   $1 = home/user/bin/etc/something...
   ```

   so I need to change IFS to "/" and then proceed this in for loop like

   ```
   while [ -e "$1" ]; do 
       for F in `$1`
           #do something
       done
   shift
   done
   ```

Is that the correct way ?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do in question 2. Regarding question 1: `${IFS#??}` takes off two characters from the left of `IFS`. Check out `man bash` for Parameter Expansion. You can also read [Bash FAQ 73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

Comment: *"I have two questions."* Then post two separate questions so we can discuss and answer them in isolation, and a single answer can eventually be accepted as the solution. Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${var#??}` is a [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). It tries to match the beginning of `$var` with the pattern written after `#`. If it does, it returns the variable `$var` with that part removed. Since `?` matches any character, this means that `${var#??}` removes the first two chars from the var `$var`.

```
$ var="hello"
$ echo ${var#??}
llo
```

So with `IFS=${IFS#??}` you are resetting [`IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) to its value after removing its two first chars.

---

To loop through the words in a `/`-delimited string, you can store the splitted string into an array and then loop through it:

```
$ IFS="/" read -r -a myarray <<< "home/user/bin/etc/something"
$ for w in "${array[@]}"; do echo "-- $w"; done
-- home
-- user
-- bin
-- etc
-- something
```